# Отличие генераторного выражения от спискового включения Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет!
Читаю Луца(Изучаем Python, 5-ое издание), возник такой вопрос. В книге сказано, что когда мы вызываем генератор функции или выражения, то он не хранит весь список в памяти, а генерирует на лету. Все понятно, ок. 
Но не понимаю вот что:

```
G = (x*2 for x in range(1,5))
print(list(G))
```

Все равно мы потом, чтобы вывести через print это выражение, мы помещаем его в лист, и это тоже самое, что и списковое включение:

```
print([x**2 for x in range(1,5)])
```

Т.е. и там и там список целиком загружается в память. Так где, в каком месте тогда генераторное выражение оптимизирует расход памяти? 
 Если вот здесь:

```
G = (x*2 for x in range(1,5))
```

, тогда мы же в любом случае в будущем, чтобы извлечь данные из генератора, мы поместим его в лист и опять же этот лист будет полностью загружен в память.

Comment: `тогда мы же в любом случае в будущем, чтобы извлечь данные из генератора, мы поместим его в лист и опять же этот лист будет полностью загружен в память.` - не обязательно. Допустим, если вам нужно будет найти конкретный элемент, то из генератора последовательно будут получены элементы до нужного, но не весь список.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое!

Comment: P.S. причем предыдущие полученные элементы не будут сохраняться в памяти, а будет храниться только текущий. В этом и состоит экономия памяти.

Answer (score 1):

Оптимизация заключается в том, что мы можем расходовать память только тогда, когда нам нужен этот список. Приведу пример. Есть некоторая функция `f`, которая принимает список, и... Ничего не делает. Важно лишь то, что она принимает список:

```
def f(l: list):
    pass
```

И у нас есть большой проект, в котором мы заранее оговариваем, какие списки используются.
Что происходит для генератора:

```
g = (a**2 + 2*a for a in range(10))

# --->
# в этом блоке происходит что-то важное
# здесь какой-то очень большой проект
# впрочем, может, и не очень большой
# --->

f(list(g))
```

В данном примере память для **списка** выделяется только в момент вызова функции, а в блоке с каким-то важным кодом лишь небольшой объём памяти выделен для хранения генератора.

Что происходит для списка:

```
g = [a**2 + 2*a for a in range(10)]

# --->
# в этом блоке происходит что-то важное
# здесь какой-то очень большой проект
# впрочем, может, и не очень большой
# --->

f(g)
```

А вот в этом примере память для списка выделена сразу, и в момент работы "важного кода" она уже занята, хотя ещё не используется.

Comment: Евгений, понял, спасибо за ответ!